# By default dropdown selection

Tags: c#, asp.net

In ASP.NET, I have a dropdown and a button. If I select a value from the dropdown and click  the button, I want it to redirect to another page and pass the selected value from the dropdown to this new page.

If anyone has an idea then please help me.

Comment: Is this asp.net? WPF? Something else?

Comment: There is no way to determine what you are asking - First off is it ASP.NET, MVC2,3,4, WinForms, Silverlight, WPF?

Comment: You probably mean dependent drop down lists. Anyway guessing a [relevant question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537217/how-do-i-force-drop-down-list-selections-on-page-load).

Comment: Googling "asp.net dropdown redirect value" gives a lot of hits.

Answer (score 3):

Try this on button click event

```
string strddlValue=Convert.ToString(DropdownList1.SelectedValue);
Response.Redirect("YourPage.aspx?Value=" + strddlValue);
```